# Asp.net Core Failed to determine the https port for redirect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I wrote an Asp web application in .net Core 5.0 for google cloud.
The applicatin delpoyed as CloudRun using the following command

```
gcloud run deploy cdm-viewer-wacore --image gcr.io/mot-cz-test/mot-cdm-viewer-wacore:v48 --platform managed --vpc-connector mot-test-connector --region=europe-west1 --project=project1 --set-env-vars=ProjectId=project1
```

The application works properly in project1, but when deploying to the same image in another project (project2), the application gives an error message

```
Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

It is quite clear that there is a difference in the settings / properties of cloudrun between the projects. What differences can cause this error?

Answer (score 1):

It would be needed to set permissions to Cloud Run to pull container images from other projects.

**For Artifacty Registry:**

- members:

  ```
      serviceAccount:service-@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com 

      role: roles/artifactregistry.reader
  ```

**For Container Registry:**

- members:

  ```
       serviceAccount:service-@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com 

       role: roles/storage.objectViewer
  ```

Also make sure that you have “**app.UseHttpsRedirection();**” in your configuration of **Startup.cs** .

If you see “**Failed to determine the https port for redirect**” in the container output, add this to your ConfigureServices(): services.AddHttpsRedirection(opt => opt.HttpsPort = 443);

Refer the links for [Https Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#require-https) and for deploying  a [Cloud Run Service using an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886156/unable-to-deploy-a-cloud-run-service-using-an-image-from-another-project) from another project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I comment the code below in Porgram.cs

```
//Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
```